# how to query where in where in neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a project that uses the spring boot and neo4j database.
I want to write a query that in one `match` getting all that have some options and minus the node that results in the second `match`. I use the `optional match` but when the second `match` has 2 nodes in response it doesn't work. I tried to use `UNWIND` operator but it doesn't work.
I must say that the result from to `match` are the same node and when the results from the second `match` are one node the query work well
in this project, I have a tweet, user and ArchivedChat nodes and the user can creator or reply on another tweet or archived tweet that create by himself.

the query that responds well for some equation is:

```
match (n:Twit)-[t:TAGS]->(y:Hashtag)
where n.isPrivate=true and y.name="#PRIVATE_xxxxx"
match (a:ArchivedChat)
where  a.username="xxxxx" and  a.chatId<>n.chatId
return distinct n
```

I search and read a lot of documents and I use `WITH` and `UNWIND` operators and don't get the proper response.

I think the situation is equal to RDBMS that when you want to use a `select` in where `IN` another `select`.

If you have any suggestion for this problem, please contact me or answer the post.

thank you

Comment: Is chatId a unique property for :ArchivedChat and :Twit nodes?

Comment: yes chatId is unique property for :ArchivedChat and :Twit

Comment: How about doing the second `MATCH` first and create a list `WITH a.chatId as forbiddenList` and then add the condition `AND NOT n.chatId IN forbiddenList` for your `n` node `MATCH ... WHERE`?

Comment: I check what you say and Unfortunately It doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
match (n:Twit)-[t:TAGS]->(y:Hashtag), (a:ArchivedChat{username:"xxxxx"})
where n.isPrivate=true and y.name="#PRIVATE_xxxxx" and a.chatId<>n.chatId
return distinct n
```

Let me know if that solved your problem.

Comment: Hi sir
It does not work 
even if you use equal in this query, it does not work and return null
thank you for your time 
I appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to collect the nodes into a list, and from there you can use the IN check to do what you want:

```
match (n:Twit)-[:TAGS]->(y:Hashtag)
where n.isPrivate=true and y.name="#PRIVATE_xxxxx"
with collect(DISTINCT n) as forbiddenList
match (a:ArchivedChat)
where  a.username="xxxxx" and NOT a IN forbiddenList
return a
```

However if you're looking for the opposite, private :Twits that aren't archived for a username, then you'll need to reverse the operations:

```
match (a:ArchivedChat)
where  a.username="xxxxx"
with collect(a) as forbiddenList
match (n:Twit)-[:TAGS]->(y:Hashtag)
where n.isPrivate=true and y.name="#PRIVATE_xxxxx" and NOT n IN forbiddenList
return DISTINCT n
```

Comment: hi sir 
I try your answer and it doesn't work
thank you for your time 
I appreciated

Comment: I think it is the cypher problem. I try to use UNWIND and with command 
it doesn't work anyway

Comment: Saying it doesn't work doesn't help advance this. Does it throw an error? Does it return wrong results? No results? And if not results, have you checked on your own to ensure spelling and case is correct, or that the pattern described actually exists? If you're modifying the query (such as with UNWIND as mentioned) can you provide the modified query?

Answer (score 0):

If the :ArchivedChat nodes show the :Twit nodes that are archived, you can do it in a more simple way by just adding :ArchivedChat label to :Twit nodes. Then you can exclude the nodes with a :ArchivedChat label through the following query:

```
MATCH (n:Twit)-[t:TAGS]->(y:Hashtag)
WHERE NOT n:ArchivedChat AND n.isPrivate=true AND y.name="#PRIVATE_xxxxx"
RETURN n
```

Answer (score 0):

I find my answer

optional match(nn:GArchivedChat) where nn.username='xxx' with collect(nn.chatId) as nn2 match (n:GTwit)-[t:TAGS]->(y:GHashtag) where n.isPrivate=true  and y.name='#PRIVATE_CHAT_xxx' and not (n.chatId  in nn2 ) return distinct n

the solution was and not (n.chatId  in nn2 )
thanks to all of users